# How can I distinguish attribute_info in JVM ClassFile?

Tags: jvm, bytecode, .class-file, jvm-bytecode

I'm digging into [The `ClassFile` Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1).

According to the document mentioned above, `attribute_info` can be appeared in various position.

My question is how can I distinguish the type of `attribute_info`s?

I know I can distinguish `constant_info`s by their `tag`s.

And How can I distinguish `attribute_info`s?

All `attribute_info` look like this.

```
attribute_info {
    u2 attribute_name_index;
    u4 attribute_length;
    u1 info[attribute_length];
}
```

And [Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5) seems have `attribute_info` of `ConstantValue`, `Synthetic`, and so on.

How can I distinguish their types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

> The `constant_pool` entry at `attribute_name_index` must be a `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` structure ([§4.4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7)) representing the name of the attribute.